# Create button and click handler with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, event-handling

Currently I am displaying a table of values, where the last column provides an "Edit" and "Delete" option. For simplicity, when they edit a row, I am just clearing each column's innerHTML and placing input fields there instead. I need to also replace the Edit/Delete links with Save/Cancel, however I need to create these buttons with JS/JQuery, attach click handlers to them append them to the innerHTML.

While I have found similar examples, I am not quite clear on how to accomplish this and would appreciate any help.

```
function editRecord(line)
{
    var zone = "<?= $data['zone']; ?>";

    // Store the original field values
    var valueName = document.getElementById("entryName" + line).innerHTML;
    var valueTTL = document.getElementById("entryTTL" + line).innerHTML;
    var valueAddress = document.getElementById("entryAddress" + line).innerHTML;

    // Replace existing row value with input fields to make edits
    document.getElementById("entryName" + line).innerHTML = "<input type='text' value='" + valueName + "'>";
    document.getElementById("entryTTL" + line).innerHTML = "<input type='text' value='" + valueTTL + "'>";
    document.getElementById("entryAddress" + line).innerHTML = "<input type='text' value='" + valueAddress + "'>";

    // Create Save button with click handler
    // Create Cancel button with click handler
    // Append these to the element below (replacing the Edit/Delete)

    document.getElementById("entryOptions" + line).innerHTML = "<input type='button' value='Save'> <input type='button' value='Cancel'>";
}
```

Comment: you can use jqgrid to simplify. http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Comment: That is really nice looking, thanks for the link. I think for this purpose I will just do it myself but will use that in the future

Comment: you're most welcome :) for this you can just create a `hidden row` with all the `input` elements and the `Save/Cancel` buttons. so when you click on the `edit` button you just `show` this row and set the existing values in those input fields and after you click `Save`, just `hide` the row and `update` your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further tinkering, I managed to figure it out. Here is the working code should it end up helping anyone else.

```
function editRecord(line)
{
    var zone = "<?= $data['zone']; ?>";

    // Store the original field values
    var originalName = document.getElementById("entryName" + line).innerHTML;
    var originalTTL = document.getElementById("entryTTL" + line).innerHTML;
    var originalAddress = document.getElementById("entryAddress" + line).innerHTML;

    // Replace existing row value with input fields to make edits
    document.getElementById("entryName" + line).innerHTML = "<input type='text' value='" + originalName + "'>";
    document.getElementById("entryTTL" + line).innerHTML = "<input type='text' value='" + originalTTL + "'>";
    document.getElementById("entryAddress" + line).innerHTML = "<input type='text' value='" + originalAddress + "'>";

    document.getElementById("entryOptions" + line).innerHTML = "";

    var saveButton = $('<button/>', {
        text: "Save",
        id: 'btn_Save' + line,
        click: function ()
        {
            // Save the changes
        }
    });

    var cancelButton = $('<button/>', {
        text: "Cancel",
        id: 'btn_Cancel' + line,
        click: function ()
        {
            document.getElementById("entryName" + line).innerHTML = originalName;
            document.getElementById("entryTTL" + line).innerHTML = originalTTL;
            document.getElementById("entryAddress" + line).innerHTML = originalAddress;
        }
    });

    $("#entryOptions" + line).append(saveButton);
    $("#entryOptions" + line).append(cancelButton);
}
```